# Create Case statement as Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, case

I have a table `PeriodRanges` of date ranges in columns `StartDate` and `EndDate` with an assigned `Period` as the 3rd column.

For example:

| StartDate | EndDate | Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2023-01-01' | '2023-01-28' | 1 |
| '2023-01-29' | '2023-02-25' | 2 |

I then have multiple tables of transactions that each have a date (entry_date) data point. My current solution is to create a case statement for each period and check if the date is between those ranges and assign the period label; however, my preference would be to maintain a date range table and either check if the date is between StartDate and EndDate and return the respective period, or create a function that assigns the period.

There may be 10 entries on date '2023-01-05' that should all return period 1, then 100 entries on date '2023-02-05' that should all return period 2, etc. as an additional column on the query

My attempts to fix:

```
CASE
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-28' THEN 'P1'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-01-29' AND '2023-02-25' THEN 'P2'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-02-26' AND '2023-03-25' THEN 'P3'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-03-26' AND '2023-04-22' THEN 'P4'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-04-23' AND '2023-05-20' THEN 'P5'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-05-21' AND '2023-06-17' THEN 'P6'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-06-18' AND '2023-07-15' THEN 'P7'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-07-16' AND '2023-08-12' THEN 'P8'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-08-13' AND '2023-09-09' THEN 'P9'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-09-10' AND '2023-10-07' THEN 'P10'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-10-08' AND '2023-11-04' THEN 'P11'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-11-05' AND '2023-12-02' THEN 'P12'
    WHEN dbo.glentry.Entry_date BETWEEN '2023-12-02' AND '2023-12-31' THEN 'P13'
    ELSE 'Non-2023'
END AS 'Period'
```

This is my current solution but I hate having to insert this in each query. I would much prefer have this within a table and use a single case statement or call a function.

Also attempted this, but I know for sure this isn't correct and I'm not sure how to fix:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ConvertDateToPeriod 
    (@Date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Period as VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT @Period =
        (CASE
            WHEN @Date BETWEEN dbo.PeriodRanges.[StartDate] AND dbo.PeriodRanges.[EndDate] THEN     dbo.PeriodRanges.[Period]
        END)
    FROM dbo.PeriodRanges

    RETURN @Period
END
```

My ideal scenario would be simply calling on the function in the select statement of queries such as:

```
SELECT
    dbo.fn_ConvertDateToPeriod (dbo.Glentry.Entry_Date),
    etc
    etc
```

Comment: why don't you create a calendar table instead ?

Comment: Note, case is an expression not a statement.

Comment: create temp table with dateRange Criteria and join this newly created table with target tables on basis of StartDate  and EndDate. This will avoid unnecessary table scan for each call of function.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you want to join the tables with your `PeriodRanges` :

```
select pr.Period , g.*
from dbo.Glentry g 
join dbo.PeriodRanges pr
on g.Entry_Date between pr.[StartDate] AND pr.[EndDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

As many comments suggested, you can create a date reference table where you can pre define your period range.

```
CREATE TABLE Date_reference(Start_Date date, End_Date date, Period varchar(5));

INSERT INTO Date_reference VALUES
('2023-01-01','2023-01-28','P1'),
('2023-01-29','2023-02-25','P2'),
('2023-02-26','2023-03-25','P3'),
('2023-03-26','2023-04-22','P4');...
```

And then joining this reference table with your main table to get your desired output.

```
SELECT 
    a.*
    ,b.Period
FROM glentry a
LEFT JOIN Date_reference b
    ON (a.Entry_date >= b.Start_Date) AND (a.Entry_date < b.End_Date)
```

This removes the need to scan a column everytime when you use a function to do the same.

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Further `max` is hardly needed for a 2 char string

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I posted that as an example. Still, edited to use a varchar

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can create the function and use it in your queries:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ConvertDateToPeriod 
    (@Date DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Period INT

    SELECT @Period = MIN(Period)
    FROM PeriodRanges
    WHERE @Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate

    RETURN CONCAT('P', CAST(@Period AS VARCHAR))
END
```

Now, you can use this function in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    dbo.fn_ConvertDateToPeriod(dbo.Glentry.Entry_Date) AS 'Period',
    -- Other columns you need
FROM
    dbo.Glentry
```